# Insert uid1 and uid2 in database when user click button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

```
<?php uid1= 1; $uid2= 2; ?>

<form class="contact" method="post">
<button value=" Send" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit">Add Friend</button></form>

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO friends (uid1, uid2) values ('$uid1', '$uid2')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: I know you, you posted same question and it got closed or downvoted and you posted again. :D. And why does this post have ajax or twitter or javascript tags on it.

Comment: i dont know how to solve it i try for 3 days and can't found this code just

Comment: You have defined **uid1** rather than **$uid1**

Comment: Why aren't the values to be insert actually in the form?

Comment: the button is twitter bootstrap and maybe ajax solve this problem like that i tried 
<p4><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button">
  Aceitar Amizade
</button>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("p4").click(function(){ 
 $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "your-phpfile.php",
        data: "uid1=" uid1, "uid2" = uid2,} 
location.reload();
  });
});

Comment: You are also switching between mysqli and mysql, use one extension or the other.

Comment: ok, thx i will change my mysql, but someone know how to send uid1 and uid2 when button press button?

can be other button like that i dont care i just need insert uid2 and uid2 in database

<p4><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="button"> Add Friend </button> <script> $(document).ready(function(){ $("p4").click(function(){ $.ajax({ type:"POST", url: "your-phpfile.php", data: "uid1=" uid1, "uid2" = uid2,} location.reload(); }); });

Comment: You're confusing client-side and server-side. PHP variable $uid1 doesn't magically exist as a javascript variable uid1. And you need to put all your relevant code in the question, not the comments, if you expect an answer.

Comment: Since the values are being posted by ajax to php, your php needs to extract them from the post.  `$uid1 = $_POST['uid1']; $uid2 = $_POST['uid2'];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In opening line.. you were missing $ for uid1. Secondly you need to send back the values in hiddent text.

```
<?php $uid1= 1; $uid2= 2; ?>

<form class="contact" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="uid1" value="<?= $uid1 ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="uid2" value="<?= $uid2 ?>" />
<button value=" Send" class="btn btn-success" type="submit" id="submit">Add Friend</button></form>

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO friends (uid1, uid2) values ('". $_POST["uid1"] ."', '". $_POST["uid1"] ."')") or die(mysqli_error());
}
```

Comment: //if (isset($_POST['submit']) dosen't work. I tested

if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$uid1= $_POST['uid1'];  
$uid2= $_POST['uid2'];     

echo $uid1; 
echo $uid2;
}

Comment: Great Job, Nawed Khan!! its almost working. THX!!

Comment: **:D Problem solved!!**

[link](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/09/jquery-ajax-post-example.html)

and i used it

`$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO amigos (uid1, uid2) values ('". $_POST["uid1"] ."', '". $_POST["uid2"] ."')") or die(mysqli_error());`

Thx ALL special to you @nawed-khan

Comment: $.post('functions2_1.php', { uid1: "<?php echo $uid1 ?>;", uid2: "<?php echo $uid2 ?>;", website: "functions2_1.php" }, function(data){